# Building compliance requirements for IOT sensors

Tags: sensor, regulations, pressure

I want to install a differential pressure sensor, ([datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0ef4/0900766b80ef40f3.pdf)), in a clients building and leave it running for a few months.

The sensor will be powered by a gateway, that will be approximately 50m away.

As you can see below, the sensor is contained in a plastic housing with metal legs.

[image]

Can I run a length of cable through the ceiling cavity to the device and leave it running for a few months unattended or are there any buildings regulations/ compliance laws to which I must adhere. i.e. from a legal perspective.

For example, does the sensor + gateway solution have to comply with the following:

EN 60950-1:2006 + A11:2009 + A12:2011 + A1:2010 + A2:2013
Information technology equipment - Safety - Part 1: General requirements

R&TTE Directive 1999/5/EC
DIRECTIVE 1999/5/EC OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL of 9 March 1999 on radio equipment and telecommunications terminal equipment and the mutual recognition of their conformity

Comment: legal aspect aside: that thing gives you an output voltage of a **maximum** of 40mV. That is very little. And there will be absolutely none left to detect after 50m cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as all your external wiring meets National Electric Code Class 2 requirements, the main thing that you need to take care with is the fire rating of the cable running through the ceiling cavity.

Most ceiling cavities in commercial buildings are used as a return air plenum. Any cable in an air plenum most have the appropriate Ft rating.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there an online guide to  National Electric Code Class 2?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not puncture the roof or a firewall I do not see any problems. You can seal the puncture after you run the cable with expanding foam.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is not a power tap off a circuit breaker panel or installing a sub-panel. NEC codes do not apply here. FCC codes do apply but only if your device transmits over the air on an un-assigned band. Even then Wi-Fi and Bluetooth already allow local use to 300 feet/160m. The cable used should already have adequate shielding.

Comment: just edited the question so it the compliance side is emphasized.  I know it can be done but is it legal?  What happens if the building burns down or the device interferes with a important frequency, (shouldn't happen but sensor not CE marked). Is it like in a domestic house, where an electrician must sign off on electrical work for insurance purposes?

Comment: I added a paragraph to clarify legal issues.

Comment: I have no way to search or prove the European requirements you stated above. Unless there is a link or a pdf link, I can go no further. I have no access to European documents. Why quote them if you have not read them and have some weird cause for concern?

Comment: I had an upvote of +1 before the European requirements were entered as part of the question, then I was down voted because my current answer did not fit the OP's new request. I will accept the down vote, but in protest as it was an after-the-fact event. I have no way of accessing the documents the OP listed after I already had a +1.

Comment: I entered the above requirements as the apply to similar devices, (i will be connecting the sensors to a gateway). +1